# Can I add the items of a subvector in a vector to another subvector in the same vector?

Tags: rust

I am writing code in which I mean to save vectors in a bigger vector.
Later, I want to append the values of one of the vectors to another and remove the vector whose values I've transferred.

I've made two attempts which have both failed and I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me out with this!

The code I use looks like this:

```rust
fn my_func(distribution: (u16, u8, u8, u8, u8, u8)) {
    let mut covered: Vec<(Vec<usize>, u16)> = vec![
        (vec![0], distribution.1.into()),
        (vec![1], distribution.2.into()),
        (vec![2], distribution.3.into()),
        (vec![3], distribution.4.into()),
        (vec![4], distribution.5.into()),
    ];

    // Attempt 1 - Error: borrowed as mutable more than once
    &covered[0].0.append(&mut covered[1].0);

    // Attempt 2 - Error: borrowed as mutable and immutable
    for i in &covered[1].0 {
        &covered[0].0.push(*i);
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to Rust, so I'm still learning about the intricacies of borrowing.
Could someone please help me understand how I am to accomplish what I want to accomplish?
Any other remarks on my coding style or on other mistakes I made are also super welcome.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Even if you didn't get borrow checker errors, the types wouldn't match up. `covered[0].0` is a `Vec<usize>` while `covered[1].0` is also a `Vec<usize>`, you can't just append it as an element. If you mean to append all of the elements from `covered[1].0` into `covered[0].0`, then use [`extend_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend). Also, the `&a.b` syntax is not `(&a).b`, but `&(a.b)`, so your leading reference is pointless.

Comment: Even if it were correct syntax, (`&mut covered[0].0).append(...)`, you need the `&mut` to mutate the vector), it'd be pointless, since Rust's deref coercion will automatically add it in.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do indeed mean to add all the elements of ```covered[1].0``` to ```covered[0].0```. I fear your feedback is of too high a level for me to comprehend. Could you maybe try to explain it in a simpler way? Maybe with an example for a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to do. Then you're trying to mutably borrow from `covered` at 2 different indices. Your approach doesn't work as `covered[0]` causes the whole `Vec` to be mutably borrowed. You can only get 1 mutable reference, which is why the subsequent `covered[1]` results in an error.

One solution to accomplish what you're trying, is to use [`split_at_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut). Then you can get 2 mutable slices from `covered`, which then each can be indexed.

This is related to what's known as ["Splitting Borrows"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html).

```rust
fn func(distribution: (u16, u8, u8, u8, u8, u8)) {
    let mut covered: Vec<(Vec<usize>, u16)> = vec![
        (vec![0], distribution.1.into()),
        (vec![1], distribution.2.into()),
        (vec![2], distribution.3.into()),
        (vec![3], distribution.4.into()),
        (vec![4], distribution.5.into()),
    ];

    let (left, right) = covered.split_at_mut(1);

    let v0 = &mut left[0];
    let v1 = &mut right[0];

    // Now both this
    v0.0.append(&mut v1.0);

    // and this works
    for i in &v1.0 {
        v0.0.push(*i);
    }
}
```

Note that as Aplet123 mentioned in the comments, [`append()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) moves all the elements from the `other` `Vec` leaving it empty. If you don't want the `other` `Vec` to be cleared, then instead use [`extend()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend) or [`extend_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend_from_slice).

---

If you know up front that you can remove the item from the `Vec`. Then you don't need to use `split_at_mut()` for this case. Then you can do as RedBorg mentioned, and just [`remove()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove) the item and borrow as you otherwise would.

```rust
fn my_func(distribution: (u16, u8, u8, u8, u8, u8)) {
    let mut covered: Vec<(Vec<usize>, u16)> = vec![
        (vec![0], distribution.1.into()),
        (vec![1], distribution.2.into()),
        (vec![2], distribution.3.into()),
        (vec![3], distribution.4.into()),
        (vec![4], distribution.5.into()),
    ];

    let mut v1 = covered.remove(1);
    let v0 = &mut covered[0];

    // Now both this
    v0.0.append(&mut v1.0);

    // and this works
    for i in &v1.0 {
        v0.0.push(*i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler stopped screaming! You're a hero!!
I'm not sure if it works yet, though. To test it, I would need to remove the now redundant v1 from covered. Still looking for a way to do that.
Thank you sooo much for the help, though!

Comment: Do you mean remove the whole `(Vec<usize>, u16)` tuple? Because if so then you can easily do `covered.remove(1);` after everything else :)

Comment: I indeed want to remove the tuple. Would covered.remove(1) remove at index 1? I thought it popped 1 item from the back. Kinda silly looking back on it. :)

Comment: Yes, [remove()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove) removes the item at the specified index. While [pop()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.pop) removes the last item from the `Vec`

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you for your help and happy holidays!

Comment: You're welcome, happy I could help, and happy holidays to you too! :)

Comment: @V.Molotov Is removing a tuple from the `covered` and add this removed element’s vector to another subvector all you want? Because then it’s very easy to remove the tuples (which transfers its ownership to your scope), take its vector, and append it to the new one. Do note that this will change the indices. `covered[0].0.append(&mut covered.remove(1).0)`

Comment: The specific example RedBorg gave doesn't work, as you'd need to `remove()` prior to borrowing `covered`. However, the premise still works, and I've updated the answer to include an example of it.